# How to get TypeScript to infer the types through multiple Higher Order components in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function-composition, higher-order-components

I'm converting a React app over to Typescript that uses a lot of functional programming patterns. The most important of those patterns is the ability to compose together multiple higher order components to return an enhanced component. What I want to happen is to have Typescript infer the types of the component at each level and finish with the component I pass to have all of the types of the HOCs above it.

I've tried this code on both 3.5.0 and the latest version of Typescript. Code wise, I've tried making the generic extend the types I want `<T extends FooProps>`, passing `FC<T & BarProps>` to the return functional component, and reversing the invocations of the HOCs.

```js
export const withFoo = <T>(Component: FC<T & FooProps>): FC<Omit<T, 'foo'>> => props => (
  <Component {...props as T} foo="foo" />
)

export const withBar = <T>(Component: FC<T & BarProps>): FC<Omit<T, 'bar'>> => props => (
  <Component {...props as T} bar="bar" />
)

export const EnhancedComponent = withFoo(
  withBar(({ bar, foo }) => { // bar exists and foo does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<BarProps>'
    console.log(bar) // types come through (bar: string)
    console.log(foo) // types don't come through (foo: any) :(
    return <div>woohoo</div> 
  }),
)
```

I want the types to come through at each level of the HOC. In the example above, I want to see this in the functional component I pass:

```js
export const EnhancedComponent = withFoo(
  withBar(({ bar, foo }) => { // both exist on the component
    console.log(bar) // bar: string
    console.log(foo) // foo: string
    return <div>woohoo</div>
  }),
)
```

Comment: Personal opinon: stacking HOCs like this is 100% overkill with the new hooks api to share stateful logic

Comment: I agree that hooks are good for most cases, but in this case we want to conditionally render other HOCs based on the result of a parent one. We also want to be able to render components to handle the error and loading states instead of handling them in render of every component so that's what lead us to HOCs.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start when looking for higher-order component typings is other packages or `@types` packages.

- [`react-i18next`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/94916045c2a5c72bef9691b94fef04fcfcdbe733/src/index.d.ts#L63-L75)
- [`react-redux`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d0cd7f859d0eb5b690ea1714ef197da819b14f99/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L173-L286) *(these are complex)*
- [`react-router-dom`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d0cd7f859d0eb5b690ea1714ef197da819b14f99/types/react-router/index.d.ts#L146-L148)

However, your use case is a bit interesting because you want the wrapped component to receive more props and each wrapping higher-order component provides one of these values.

Given that, here is one potential solution. A few things to point out:

- Assuming you want to allow any component type (class or function), reaching for the [`React.ComponentType`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d0cd7f859d0eb5b690ea1714ef197da819b14f99/types/react/index.d.ts#L71) is probably what you want.
- I try to avoid casts but it looks like this is still a shortcoming (issue) with TypeScript. These two issues looked relevant: [#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) & [#28748](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28748)
- `Omit` is added for reference because before it doesn't exist before `3.5` (I was testing in Codesandbox which at this time is still at `3.3`)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// This exists in TypeScript 3.5+
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface FooProps {
  foo: string;
}

interface BarProps {
  bar: string;
}

export const withFoo = <Props extends FooProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, keyof FooProps>> => props => (
  <Component {...props as Props} foo="foo" />
);

export const withBar = <Props extends BarProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<Props>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<Props, keyof BarProps>> => props => (
  <Component {...props as Props} bar="bar" />
);

const WrappedComponent = ({ bar, foo, more }) => {
  console.log(more);
  console.log(bar);
  console.log(foo);
  return <div>woohoo</div>;
};

const EnhancedComponent = withFoo(withBar(WrappedComponent));

const App = () => <EnhancedComponent more="more" />;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks you for giving it a try. I tried your solution, but it looks like it's losing the types on the way down. Here's a Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-bas-h8psx?fontsize=14

Comment: Hmm, yea, I'm not sure the exact cause but there are some fairly complex typings. Is there any reason the component has to be defined within the call to the HOCs? In my solution, I declared it outside and that appears to work as expected: `const Wrapped = ({ bar, foo, more }) => { return null; }; const EnhancedComponent = withFoo(withBar(Wrapped));`

Comment: The reason is because we want the types to be inferred in the wrapped component. By declaring a `Wrapped` component outside of the HOC, you lose the type safety on the props you pass it.